# problem merge record in multiselect picklist in visualforce and apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller, multi-select, merge

I have got some problem, can anyone help me solve this one?

[image: here my problem]

Here is my controller

```
public LIST<SelectOption> getallEmployee(){      
        LIST<HREMPINFO__c> empMember = [SELECT Id, Name, Full_Name__r.Name FROM HREMPINFO__c WHERE Id IN 
                                        (SELECT Employee_No__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod)
                                        ORDER BY Name];

        LIST<HREMPASSIGNMENT__c> empAssignment = [SELECT Position_Name__c, Position_Name__r.Name, Employee_No__c  FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c];

        LIST<SelectOption> empList = new LIST<SelectOption>();

        for(HREMPINFO__c eM : empMember){
            for(HREMPASSIGNMENT__c eA : empAssignment){
                if(eA.Employee_No__c == eM.Id){
                    picklistVal = eM.Full_Name__r.Name + ' - ' + eM.Name + ' - ' +eA.Position_Name__r.Name;
                    empList.add(new SelectOption(eM.Id, picklistVal));}
                }
            }
            return empList;
        }
```

Comment: You can Convert 'empAssignment' List as Set.

Comment: how the body of SET, can gv me the code how i convert it? @SFDCMafia

Comment: Better to create MAP of  Employee_No__c and Position_Name__r.Name MAP<String, String> empAssignment, Since you need name value in your picklist.

Comment: i dont understand, can u modify my code and post it here? i want to see it through the difference of my code , so i can understand it, hehe @SFDCMafia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public LIST<SelectOption> getallEmployee(){      
    LIST<HREMPINFO__c> empMember = [SELECT Id, Name, Full_Name__r.Name FROM HREMPINFO__c WHERE Id IN 
                                    (SELECT Employee_No__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod)
                                    ORDER BY Name];

    LIST<HREMPASSIGNMENT__c> empAssignment = [SELECT Position_Name__c, Position_Name__r.Name, Employee_No__c  FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c];

    LIST<SelectOption> empList = new LIST<SelectOption>();

    MAP<String, String> picklistVal  = new MAP<String, String>();

    for(HREMPINFO__c eM : empMember){
    for(HREMPASSIGNMENT__c eA : empAssignment){
        if(eA.Employee_No__c == eM.Id){
            if(!picklistVal.containskey(eA.Employee_No__c)){
                picklistVal.put(eA.Employee_No__c, eM.Full_Name__r.Name + ' - ' + eM.Name + ' - ' +eA.Position_Name__r.Name);
                empList.add(new SelectOption(eM.Id, picklistVal.get(eA.Employee_No__c)));}
            }
        }
    }


        return empList;
    }
```

Comment: Changed your variable 'picklistVal' from list to MAP. comment your previous defined 'picklistVal' variable. Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for feedback , but now i got new error, the error message :
Illegal assignment from String to Map<String,String>
@SFDC Mafia

Comment: f(!picklistVal.containskey(eA.Employee_No__c)){
                    picklistVal.put(eA.Employee_No__c, eM.Full_Name__r.Name + ' - ' + eM.Name + ' - ' +eA.Position_Name__r.Name);
                    empList.add(new SelectOption(eM.Id, picklistVal.get(eA.Employee_No__c)));}
                }

Comment: thanks alot sir! it work! @SFDC Mafia
btw can u explain to me how map works sir?

Comment: Go through http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/01/06/fun-with-salesforce-collections/ . This might help you to understand

Comment: oke! thankyou for the reference @SFDC Mafia